# Active record delete_all issue with empty field

Tags: ruby, activerecord, activemodel

My Course model has a field called user_ids which is an array of ObjectIds.

I am trying to find all courses with non empty user_ids and unset only the user_id field.

```
list = Course.where({ :user_ids.nin => [[], nil] })
list.each do |course|
  course.user_ids = []
  course.save 
end
```

However, I always seem to get two courses which have:

```
"user_ids" : [ ObjectId("560dc9998b3c5b003f000000") ]
```

Is my query wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question reads that you want to find all the courses that have empty or nil `user_ids` and then set them to `[]`. So you want to find courses that have `user_ids == []` and set it to `[]`...? Why? It sounds like you want to set something equal to what it already is.

Comment: Sorry, non empty. Edited the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the `where.not` method.

`Course.where.not(user_ids: [[], nil])`

[You can read more about `where.not` here](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/11/15/five-active-record-features-you-should-be-using/#wherenot)

The reason your original query did not work is because you tried to call the `.nin` method on the `:user_id` symbol, which is not a method that a symbol can accept.

Comment: Agreed. But can you please explain why mine fails?

Comment: Edited with an explanation of why your code failed.